# c++ float decimal places, the number could suddenly have '05' at the end

Tags: c++

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //timer1();
    cout.precision(30);

    char coordinates[100]="-88.5652389526367,39.1187744140625,0";
    char* chars_array_coordinates=strtok(coordinates,",");
    cout<<"chars_array_coordinates"<<chars_array_coordinates<<"\n";
    char* chars_array_coordinates_1=strtok(NULL,",");
    cout<<"chars_array_coordinates"<<chars_array_coordinates_1<<"\n";

    float coordinates_Latitude=atof(chars_array_coordinates);
    cout<<"coordinates_Latitude"<<coordinates_Latitude<<"\n";
    float coordinates_Latitude_1=atof(chars_array_coordinates_1);
    cout<<"coordinates_Latitude_1"<<coordinates_Latitude_1<<"\n";
}
```

the output is

```
chars_array_coordinates=-88.5652389526367
chars_array_coordinates=39.1187744140625
coordinates_Latitude=-88.565238952636705
coordinates_Latitude=-39.1187744140625
```

string to float: -88.5652389526367 to -88.565238952636705 <-the number could suddenly have '05' at the end. What happen?

Comment: Floats are approximate. They can't represent all numbers exactly. (That's the answer to most floating-point questions.)

Comment: Quite surprised that you get 15 digit accuracy.  Are you using 64-bit floats?  floats on a 32 bit machine only have 6 digits precision.  On a 32-bit machine you need to use a double for 15 digit precision.

Answer (score 2):

As commented above floating point numbers are approximate. You may loose precision while using them. You must read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Actually when the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small [rounding error](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/) even before the calculation happens.

To avoid this problem you can better use decimal or double.